# Iterate all connections in a websocketpp server

Tags: c++, websocket

I modified the 'Extended Connection Storage' example at http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/storing-connection-specificsession-information and can update some data sent from a client. When data changes I'd like to propagate that to all connected clients. I want to iterate all connections but at the bottom the documentation states 'Note, this example has no ability to enumerate all connections.'.

Shall I use the examples on http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/server-initiated-messages instead?

Pseudocode:

```
void on_message(connection_hdl hdl, server::message_ptr msg) {
    if (jdata["type"] == "update") {
        for (auto it : connections) {
            m_server.send(hdl, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Time off watching TV with the kids is quality time. There I suddenly remembered the other examples on websocketpp:

```
private:
    typedef std::set<connection_hdl, std::owner_less<connection_hdl>> con_list;
    con_list m_connections;

void on_open(connection_hdl hdl) {
    m_connections.insert(hdl);
}

void on_close(connection_hdl hdl) {
    m_connections.erase(hdl);
}


if (jdata["type"] == "update") {
    for (auto it : m_connections) {
        msg->set_payload(table.dump());
            m_server.send(it, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you compare two connections? connection_hdl is a weak_ptr and does not seem easy to compare.
Getting the socket (an integer) from the connection can be used as something unique but I couldn't find how to get it from having a websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this but I seem to recall it will broadcast a message to all clients connected, think publish/subscribe as in Apache Kafka.